# On the existence of magic squares of every order different from $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, magic-square

I was reading about magic squares and suppose that we speak here only of the magic squares that have in itself numbers from $1$ to $n^2$.

It is easy to see that we cannot have $2$x$2$ magic square because we cannot arrange numbers $1,2,3,4$ in such a square so that the sum of numbers in every row, column and diagonals is the same number.

But the natural questions that comes is:

> Is it true (if it is proven, can someone point me to some references?) that for every $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{2\}$ there exists at least one $n$x$n$ magic square?

Comment: Yes. There are algorithms given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Method_for_constructing_a_magic_square_of_odd_order), for example.

Comment: @rogerl Thank you. Do you know does there exists any unifying proof which deals with all cases at once?

Comment: It's not hard to see, just by setting up $2n+2$ homogeneous equations in $n^2$ unknowns, that there is a magic square with common sum $0$ if $n>2$. Adding a constant to each square then produces a magic square with a nonzero sum. It is not obvious (to me), however, that the elements can be chosen so that the entries are $1$ through $n^2$.

Comment: @rogerl: That looks like a very weak argument to me! You seem to consider the zero matrix as a magic square.Or perhaps I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 2):

Sierpinski in his classical book, [*Elementary Number theory*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ktCZ2MvgN3MC&pg=PA436&lpg=PA436&dq=that%20there%20exist%20magic%20squares&source=bl&ots=DtGx1ayvSU&sig=FTBYUYuKy4KlpA42U0npY3KHwzM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNscWa4YzMAhWIHpoKHVc4BqsQ6AEIRjAF#v=onepage&q=that%20there%20exist%20magic%20squares&f=false), explains :

> It is proved that there exist magic squares for any n >=3 (cf. L.Bieberbach).

referring to an article (in german) by Bieberbach (1954).

Moreover, Sierpinski claims to present a proof due to  Makowski but the proof seems to depend on a conjecture (the so-called Schinzel conjecture or  conjecture H in his book, cf. page 133).

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#A_method_of_constructing_a_magic_square_of_doubly_even_order) gives a technique for constructing examples.  For odd order, the elements from $kn+1$ to $(k+1)n$ are written on a (broken) diagonal so that each row and column contain one of each residue $\bmod n$ and one of each block $[1,n], [n+1,2n], \dots [n^2-n+1,n^2]$.  The ones that are a multiple of $4$ are constructed by reflecting some of the numbers through the center.  Those of the form $4n+2$ are formed from a square of size $2n+1$